# convert text form-data curl request into java code using rest template

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

```
curl --location --request POST 'some/api' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--form 'name=testing' \
--form 'Key=testing' \
--form 'Client_Code=123' \
--form 'userid=123' \
```

Curl request converted using RestTemplate like below. It is not sending the form-data in the body.

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    // headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA); tried this also

    MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    formData.add("MsgCode", "testing");
    formData.add("Key", "testing");
    formData.add("Client_Code", "123");
    formData.add("userid", "123");

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(formData, headers);
    try {
      ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate
          .exchange("some/api", HttpMethod.POST,
             request, String.class);
```

Comment: Any error message during restTemplate call? or what do you mean by  saying `It is not sending`

Comment: form-data as the request body is not coming to API.

Comment: The cURL request is working? Do you have access to that API or can check that the request even reached this API? Or everything is OK except for empty body?

Comment: Yes, the curl request is working. I can't check what the request is going to API. According to the response, empty body is going there.

Answer (score 0):

old post, but was looking for something similar and saw nothing wrong other than the key you sent was

```
formData.add("MsgCode", "testing");
```

Should have been

```
formData.add("name", "testing");
```